# Python App Engine architecture for entity with multiple languages

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, app-engine-ndb

I am creating an NDB model in App Engine called "Chair". The model will have entities with names such as "blue chair" and "red chair". However, I'd like users to be able to store chair property values in multiple languages/locales.

The best approach that I've found so far would be to have a ndb.KeyProperty() on the chair object called 'language_parent' and another string field called "language". The key property could then lookup to the original chair entity.

Is this the best architecture for this type of scenario?

Comment: Or you can have a language string property with choices!

Comment: this question isn't clear enough... please provide a code sample of the NDB model classes you have defined already, then I can give you further advice

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for displaying names in a desired language, it would be better to have any language string stored in the entity itself. You could for example have a property names in for format of:

```
name-<ISO 639-5 code>
```

Where [ISO 639-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-5) is a standard for [3 letter](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-5/id.php) (alpha-3) codes for languages. This means that the English name would be stored in a property called 'name-eng' and a 'name-gem' for German. 'name' for itself could be reserved for the original/default/native language name so you always have a direct value to display if no language is selected.

When you retrieve the entity, you can either directly get the language property designed (if it exists), or loop of the property names starting with 'name-' to find all available languages.

With NDB, you'll need to use the [`ndb.Expando class`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/creating-entity-models#expando). you can get the list of properties using the special `_properties` attribute.